# Best way to schedule tasks to run in the future dynamically using celery + sqs

Tags: amazon-web-services, celery, schedule

So I'm struggling to figure out the optimal way to schedule some events to happen at some point in the future using celery. An example of this is when a new user has registered, we want to send them an email the next day.

We have celery setup and some of you may allude to the `eta` parameter when calling `apply_async`. However that won't work for us, as we use SQS which has a visibility timeout that would conflict and generally the `eta` param shouldn't be used for lengthy periods.

One solution we've implemented at this point is to create events and store them in the database with a 'to-process' timestamp (refers to when to process the event). We use the celery beat scheduler with a task that runs literally every second to see if there are any new events that are ready to process. If there are, we carry out the subsequent tasks.

This solution works, although it doesn't feel great since we're queueing a task every second on SQS. Any thoughts or ideas on this would be great?

Comment: Hey there, looking into the same kind of problem right now. Any updates on this? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe some other solutions have arisen to make this easier. But we opted to use SFN on AWS where we setup a state machine with a delay state (wait x minutes/hours etc.) before carrying out some other AWS action (trigger lambda in our case). This does mean that you end up delegating application level logic to the cloud and so you have to manage the logging/perf monitoring on that front.

Practically speaking we found it useful for implementations like sending emails where the state machine has two steps, one to wait a certain amount of time and the other that sends the email via a lambda.

Comment: I've had this issue, to help address it, I developed a service scheduledwebhook.com. It allows you to specify when an event should be triggered and the destination for the data. If this sounds like it might meet your needs, check it out.